# Changes in jQuery 1.10x affecting "select element" behavior and scripting?

Tags: jquery, html, wordpress, jquery-ui

Hoping someone might provide some insight into the specific changes in jQuery 1.10x affecting 
select element behavior and scripting?

While updating a Wordpress plugin to utilize WP's native jQuery UI, tabs, widgets etc. 
(*as opposed to enqueing via Google's AJAX Libraries API*) I'm experiencing difficulty with 
a variety of unexpected select element behaviors (and failings) when running **jQuery 1.10** as compared to the behavior running **jQuery 1.9x** (*or less*).

I'd have put up a fiddle for this, but as jsfiddle does not yet support jQuery UI above 1.9x,  I offer the following as **just ONE** example of the kind of anomalies I'm seeing around select element behavior in 1.10 ...

Upon clicking the "***Click Me***" button, and then selecting "***Deposit***" from the "***Transaction Type***" drop-down in the resulting dialog,
the following demo should:

1. show().change() the hidden "**.deposit_types**" select element which --
2. having only a **single option** -- *should*
3. trigger the **.offset_select.change** event to alert
4. "**Offset Type = deposits_pending**" and "**Offset Label =Deposits
   Pending**"

**Using jQuery 1.9x or below, this works as expected,** but 1.10

1. shows the ".deposit_types" select element as having an empty first option which
2. causes the .offset_select.change event to fail which then
3. alerts "**Offset Type = null\nOffset Label =''**"

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <link type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"-->

    <!--script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <link type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"-->
    <script>
        jQuery(function(){
            jQuery('body').on('click','.add_trans', function()
            {   /* INITIATE TRANSACTION / LOAD REGISTER */
                var btn = jQuery(this),
                    trans_list = btn.prop('name'),
                    reg_html = jQuery('#'+trans_list+'_register').html(),
                    reg_id = 'reg_'+trans_list,
                    register = jQuery('.reg_div').prop('id',reg_id).html(reg_html),
                    account = btn.prop('title'),
                    title = "Record a Transaction in the "+account+" Register",
                register.prop('title', title).dialog(
                {   modal: true,
                    width:600,
                    resizable: false,
                    position: [250, 150],
                    open: function() { reg_events(account); },
                    buttons:[ { text: "Ok", click: function() { flush_dlg(); } } ]
                });
            });
        });
        function reg_events(account)
        {   /*  INITIALIZE TRANSACTION REGISTER DIALOG EVENTS */
            var register = jQuery('.reg_div');
            register.on('change','.trans_type', function()
            {
                var trans_type = jQuery(this).val();
                register.find('.offset_sel').val('').hide();
                if(trans_type =='Deposit') register.find('.deposit_types').show().change();
            });
            register.on('change', '.offset_sel', function()
            {   /* ADD REGISTER OFFSET ACCOUNT TYPE SELECTS */
                var offset_sel = jQuery(this),
                    offset_type = offset_sel.val(),
                    offset_label = jQuery("option:selected", offset_sel).text();
                alert('Offset Type ='+offset_type+'\n Offset Label ='+offset_label);
            });
        }
        function flush_dlg()
        {   /*DESTROY DIALOG - REMOVE AND REPLACE ITS CONTAINER */
            var selector = ".reg_div",
                replace_me = "class='reg_div'";
            jQuery(selector).dialog( "destroy" );
            jQuery(selector).remove();
            jQuery('#main_tabs').after("<div "+replace_me+"></div>");
        }
    </script>
    <style> .register{ display:none;} .reg_div, .ui-widget {font-size:smaller; } </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id='main_tabs'>
        <div class='reg_div'></div>
        <!--TABS CONTENT HERE -- MAY INCLUDE VARIOUS 'add_trans' CLASS BUTTONS && 'register' CLASS DIVs -->
        <button class='add_trans' name='petty_cash' title='Petty Cash'> Click Me! </button>
        <div id="petty_cash_register" class="register">
            <select class="trans_type">
                <option value="">Transaction Type</option>
                <option value="Deposit">Deposit</option>
                <option value="Withdrawal">Withdrawal</option>
            </select>
            <select style="display: none;" class="offset_sel deposit_types split">
                <option value="deposits_pending">Deposits Pending</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding your code... Where exactly within your code do you think you're having a problem? I don't see anything wrong with it so far.

Comment: @KevinB
if(trans_type =='Deposit') register.find('.deposit_types').show().change();
1.9.x and under will .show() the ".deposit_types" classed select element. 
Having only a single option, the change event on that element (which also has the .offset_sel class) 
offset_type and offset_labels variables are then defined by the .offset_sel change function. 
Using 1.10x however, running show().change() on the ".deposit_types" classed select element causes the 
element to be "shown" with an errant/empty first option

Comment: @KevinB
if you run it locally, first under 1.9x or less, and then under 1.10 I think the difference should become obvious.

Comment: Right, but you should narrow this down. there's no way jQuery ui is changing how selecting elements works.

Comment: Well, you wouldn't think so... but running this code verbatim, changing ONLY the jQuery versions and the behavior is decidedly different. Try it!

Comment: Like this? http://jsfiddle.net/caAdL/ seems to be working for me, when the fiddle is properly built using external resources.

Comment: I see the problem. well, i see the misunderstanding. The problem you are having has NOTHING to do with jQuery UI, it's the update from jQuery 1.9 to jQuery 1.10. When i upgrade to 1.10, i see what you are seeing. Now with that in mind, lets strip jQuery UI out of the equation.

Comment: Here's your code without jQuery UI presenting the same problem: http://jsfiddle.net/caAdL/1/ If you remove `.val('')` it works. http://jsfiddle.net/caAdL/2/ this is a demonstration of why it is so important to simplify your code when you're debugging. Remove the irrelevant parts.

Comment: Setting the value to `''` when there isn't an option with a value of `''` is what's causing your problem.